# How can I dynamically using for loop, push functions with different arguments to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, parallel-processing, async.js

Currently I am trying to run in parallel the same function with different arguments using Node.JS

For this I use Async.js and i am struggling trying to push/stack functions to an array. The problem is that the functions are executed with the same arguments. This is what I have:

```
var async = require("async");
var array = [];
var x = [1,2,3,4];

// This portion of code works perfect and the arguments are passed perfectly
// The results that i am getting are: [100, 200, 300, 400]
array.push(function(callback){ callback(null,calculate(x[0]))});
array.push(function(callback){ callback(null,calculate(x[1]))});
array.push(function(callback){ callback(null,calculate(x[2]))});
array.push(function(callback){ callback(null,calculate(x[3]))});

// This portion of code does not work and I dont know why ... 
// The results that i am getting are: [400, 400, 400, 400]
// Obviusly the function is receiving the same argument a=4 everytime is called
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
    array.push(function(callback){ callback(null,calculate(x[i]))});
}

async.parallel(array,function(err,result){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    return;
    }
    console.log("Results are: " + result);
});


function calculate(a) {
  return a*100
}
```

Any idea of what is wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this, it is an issue of closure

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
   (function(i){
    array.push(function(callback){ callback(null,calculate(x[i]))});
   })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is what you need.

```
'use strict';
for (let i=0;i<3;i++){
    array.push(function(callback){ callback(null,calculate(x[i]))});
}
```

Comment: absolutely, i didn't use let as didn't know if he/she was using a transpiler - but yes, "let" is a good avenue too!